# How does hash of hashMap guarantee no more than 8 collisions?

Tags: java

I'm asking experts, so there's no need for simple answers. 
In the descriprion of `HashMap`'s `hash` method says:

> This function ensures that `hashCode`s that differ only by
>    constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
>    number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).

But how do they do this? The method shows deterministic behavior - if you pass the same `hashCode` as a parameter, you get the same result. So, if you pass more than 8 objects as keys of the map (and if you don't overlap the load factor), they will be put in the same bucket. How, then, does the method guarantee the limited number of collisions?

In order to test whether I am right, I used this. Say we want a 32 sized map with a load factor of 0.75. You can put 23 objects into the map and it won't resize.

```
Map testMap = new HashMap<SimpleHashCodeObject, String>(32);
```

Then you define some objects:

```
public class SimpleHashCodeObject {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        SimpleHashCodeObject that = (SimpleHashCodeObject) o;
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if(name.equals("a")) return 1;
        if (name.equals("b"))  return 2;
        else return 3;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And, finally, you populate everything:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map testMap = new HashMap<SimpleHashCodeObject, String>(32);


    for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
        SimpleHashCodeObject sho = new SimpleHashCodeObject();
        sho.setName("a");
        testMap.put(sho, new Integer(i).toString());
    }

    for(int i = 13; i <= 23; i++){
        SimpleHashCodeObject sho2 = new SimpleHashCodeObject();
        sho2.setName("b");
        testMap.put(sho2, new Integer(i).toString());
    }
}
```

In the debug window I can see 2 buckets in this map, each containing more than 8 elements.

[image]

How come this is the case? Can you clarify the situation?

Comment: "hashCodes that differ only by constant multiples at each bit position" Your "example" class has *identical* hash codes.

Comment: This is an example of bad hashCodes implementation !

Comment: What doe really stay behind "hashCodes that differ only by constant multiples at each bit position" - say hash1 == 2, hash2 == 8  or so?

Comment: BTW - hashcodes that differ - go to different buckets automatically - without any additional handling in need. So the hash method still looks suspicious.